# how to jest test connected component which has api calls in componentDidMount

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, connected-components

I am trying to test a connected component but it does not seem to make the api calls in the componentDidMount function. I need it to make the api calls so i can test the how this component woudl render depending on the values returned from api calls. api calls are made by axios using redux actions. everything stored in redux.

here is my test

```
it('should dispatch an action on mount', () => {
        const component =  shallow(
            <ProcessingStatus store={store}/>
        );
        const didMount = jest.spyOn(component, 'componentDidMount');
        expect(didMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        //console.log(component.html())
        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);

    });
```

this is the `componentDidMount` in my component

```
componentDidMount() {
        const {
            matches: { params: { id } },
            processingStatus,
            securityStatus,
            routingStatus,
            soxStatus,
            remedyStatus,
            user: {
                priv: {
                    my_sox_requests,
                    view_remedy
                }
            }
        } = this.props;
        let params = 'id=' + id;
        if(processingStatus !== undefined){
            processingStatus(params)
            .catch(thrown => {
                console.log(thrown);
            });
        }
        if(securityStatus !== undefined){
            securityStatus(params)
                .catch(thrown => {
                    console.log(thrown);
                });
        }
        if(routingStatus !== undefined){
            routingStatus(params)
                .catch(thrown => {
                    console.log(thrown);
                });
        }
        if(my_sox_requests && my_sox_requests === 'on' && soxStatus !== undefined){
            soxStatus(params)
                .catch(thrown => {
                    console.log(thrown);
                });
        }

        if(view_remedy && view_remedy === 'on' && remedyStatus !== undefined){
            remedyStatus(params)
                .catch(thrown => {
                    console.log(thrown);
                });
        }
    }
```

Error i get is

```
FAIL  tests/jest/components/common/ProcessingStatus/index.test.js
  <ProcessingStatus />
    ✓ should render with given state from Redux store (90ms)
    ✕ should dispatch an action on mount (7ms)

  ● <ProcessingStatus /> › should dispatch an action on mount

    Cannot spy the componentDidMount property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

      85 |             <ProcessingStatus store={store}/>
      86 |         );
    > 87 |         const didMount = jest.spyOn(component, 'componentDidMount');
         |                               ^
      88 |         expect(didMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      89 |
      90 |         //console.log(component.html())

      at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:841:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/jest/components/common/ProcessingStatus/index.test.js:87:31)
```

I tried with `const didMount = jest.spyOn(ProcessingStatus.prototype, 'componentDidMount');` and error i get is

```
  ● <ProcessingStatus /> › should dispatch an action on mount

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

      85 |         );
      86 |         const didMount = jest.spyOn(ProcessingStatus.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    > 87 |         expect(didMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
         |                          ^
      88 |
      89 |         //console.log(component.html())
      90 |         expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
```

I managed to test didmount being called but not sure how to check if the api calls have been made.

```
it('should run componentDidMount', () => {
        spy = jest.spyOn(ProcessingStatus.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
        component = mount(
            <ProcessingStatus store={store}/>
        );
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching a similar question here and found out that you have some order errors:

1. you should set the spyOn componentDidMount before the shallow(Component)
2. you should ask for Component.prototype.componentDidMount was called after shallow component

```
jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, 'componentDidMount')

shallow(<Component/>)

expect(Component.prototype.componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

if the component expect to receive props functions that are going to be called inside the componentDidMount, you should add them when shallow Component like

```
const mockExpectedFunction= jest.fn()
shallow(<Component expectedFunction={mockExpectedFunction} />
```